# Is it possible to sql count() only the first instances of a column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I would like to count the number of *initial* company subscribes for each user.

In the dataset below, I want a count of `3` for user1 and a count of `0` for user2.  Because both of the companies subscribed by user2 had previously been subscribed by user1.

```
id    user    companyId    activity 
-----------------------------------   

1     1       101          subscribe
2     1       101          unsubscribe
3     1       102          subscribe
4     1       103          subscribe

5     2       102          unsubscribe
6     2       102          subscribe
7     2       103          unsubscribe
8     2       103          subscribe
```

Is this possible in SQL, and if so, how would I go about it?

Any improvements to question wording would be welcome as I've struggled to explain this clearly.

Comment: does the id represent the order in time?

Comment: Yea it does. The lower the id, the earlier it was created.

Comment: Assuming that the `id` column is an `IDENTITY` column, I wouldn't rely on it being representative of insert time.  Although unusual, there are scenarios where the id can be allocated out-of-order.  Better to have a datetime field in there...

Comment: Yo there. Agreed. In this instance it's guaranteed, but pretty easy to swap out the id field for a datetime if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the window function [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql):

```
select  [user],
        count(case when activity = 'subscribe' and rn = 1 then 1 end)
from   (select [user],
               activity,
               row_number() over (partition by companyId order by id) rn
        from   mytable) as base
group by [user]
```

See it run on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/FDNY55244)

Comment: I would never have been able to come up with that! Thank you. Also for the link to test it. That is a first class answer and very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery (`fs` below) to get the `id` associated with the first subscription to each company, and then count companies per user for that subset, as follows:

```
select
    user,
    count(*) as initial_subscriptions
from
    (
        select companyId, min(id) as id
        from the_table
        where activity = 'subscribe'
        group by companyId
    ) as fs
    inner join the_table on the_table.id = fs.id
group by
    user;
```

Comment: I don't think this will output a line for user2 in the example. Also you would need to add an alias for the second column in the inner query : `min(id) as id`.

Comment: Thanks very much. I choose the other answer as that was ultimately the one I used,  but I voted this one up.